# LWJGL fullscreen slow (er)

Tags: lwjgl

I notice that fullscreen mode with LWJGL takes up a lot of resources. I looked at it with my profiler, and see that Display.update takes a considerable lot of time. Is there a solution for this? Is it a natural occurrence?

Comment: Are you certain it isn't just waiting for the vertical retrace?

Comment: Could be, but why would it have a lower fps then?

Answer (score 1):

`Display.update` is the main method that contains all the pipeline logic with communication with OpenGL so by nature it is going to be the largest function of the application, much like `Game.doLogic` for instance. Because it contains all the OpenGL communication it is heavily influenced by OpenGL which in turn influences hardware, and obviously the larger the window the more pixels it has to draw, among other things, thus making the frame/render time longer and so finally influencing `Display.update`. So yes it is natural for it to take longer the bigger the frame's resolution.

How much more "resources" exactly? Does "resources" mean hardware or function timings or memory usage? I don't see much reason for `Display.update` to take up a noticeable amount of memory the larger the frame's dimensions.